# Need to remove rows and update other rows when conditions are met in a csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delete-row

I am fairly new to python.  I am working with a csv file that contains the following

```
Name, Description, Price
Comp1, comp desc, 60
Comp1, comp desc, 100
Comp1, comp desc, 250
Comp1, comp desc, 90
Comp1, comp desc, 125
Comp1, comp desc, 600
Comp1, comp desc, 395
```

...

I am trying to read the file, if there are any duplicates (based on name), remove those. Then if the price < 50 remove those. Then add a new column called 'Quality'. then if the price is < 80 set the "quality for that row to "Average" , if the price is < 125 set price to "High".

I am trying to use Pandas for this (I tried using the csv module but could not figure it out after 3 days...)

so far I am able to add a new column. I am not sure how to delete a row if it meets a condition (surprisingly, I could not find anything that matched my criteria in the posts)

I tried the following but I get an error saying "the truth value of a series is ambiguous...

code:

```
    #python 3.6
    import pandas as pd

    csv_input = pd.read_csv("d:\python programs\chairs.csv")
    csv_input["Quality"] = ""

    csv_input.loc[csv_input["Price"] > 50 and csv_input["Price"] < 125, "Quality"] = "Average"
    csv_input.loc[csv_input["Price"] > 125, "Quality" = "High"]

    csv_input.to_csv("d:\python programs\output2.csv", index=False)

    print (csv_input.iloc[:, 2])
```

the last line is just a check that I am working with any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Update:
I was able to update the code to get it to do some of what I want, however I still need to understand how to delete rows where price >= 50 (example).

Here is the updated code:

```
    import pandas as pd

    csv_input = pd.read_csv("d:\python programs\chairs.csv")
    csv_input["Quality"] = ""

    'This line set the Quality to average if the value is ,= 125'

    csv_input.loc[csv_input["Price"] <= 125, "Quality"] = "Average" 

    'This line sets the Quality to high if the Price is above 125'

    csv_input.loc[csv_input["Price"] > 125, "Quality"] = "High"

    'This line writes to an output file'

    csv_input.to_csv("d:\python programs\output2.csv", index=False)



    print (csv_input.iloc[:, 2])
```

Thanks again for all the comments and the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Use `&` instead of `and`

Comment: You need to assign the results of your .loc calls to a variable.

Comment: update: okay so in working with it and reading, yes I need to use & instead of and... but I still get the following error: (base) d:\python programs>python Pd_Add_Col_5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pd_Add_Col_5.py", line 7, in <module>
    csv_input.loc[csv_input["Price"] > 50 & csv_input["Price"] < 125, "Quality"] = "Average"
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1576, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I did manage to get it to do some of what I am looking for by doing the following.   import pandas as pd

csv_input = pd.read_csv("d:\python programs\chairs.csv")
csv_input["Quality"] = ""

'This line set the Quality to average if the value is ,= 125'

csv_input.loc[csv_input["Price"] <= 125, "Quality"] = "Average" 

'This line sets the Quality to high if the Price is above 125'

csv_input.loc[csv_input["Price"] > 125, "Quality"] = "High"

'This line writes to an output file'

csv_input.to_csv("d:\python programs\output2.csv", index=False)

print (csv_input.iloc[:, 2])

Comment: how can i remove rows where the price is <= 50 for example? Thanks

Comment: You need to accept one of answers

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` operator instead of `and` in indexes, also wrap conditions up in parenthesesif they are separated by some logical operator:

```py
import pandas as pd

csv_input = pd.read_csv("d:\python programs\chairs.csv")
csv_input["Quality"] = ""

csv_input.loc[(csv_input["Price"] > 50) & (csv_input["Price"] < 125), "Quality"] = "Average"
# in the next string '[' just moved to the right place
csv_input.loc[csv_input["Price"] > 125, "Quality"] = "High"

csv_input
Out:
       Name     Description     Price   Quality
0     Comp1       comp desc     60      Average
1     Comp1       comp desc     100     Average
2     Comp1       comp desc     250        High
3     Comp1       comp desc     90      Average
4     Comp1       comp desc     125     
5     Comp1       comp desc     600        High
6     Comp1       comp desc     395        High
```

Explanation:
`csv_input["Price"] < 125` returns following pd.Series with boolean values:

```py
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
```

In python, `and` kwd can't be overloaded, but the `&` or other (bitwise) logical operators operator can. 
So, `(csv_input["Price"] > 50) & (csv_input["Price"] < 125)` returns pd.Series again (more info about indexing):

```py
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
```

This series will be used as boolean mask for the `.loc[]`. (Looks the same as the former series because `(csv_input["Price"] > 50)` all `True`)

If you wish to drop duplicated lines, try [`pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates().`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the rows by doing,

```
csv_input = csv_input.loc[csv_input['Price'] > 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's recreate your DF

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DF
csv_input = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Comp1', 'Comp2', 'Comp3', 'Comp1', 'Comp2', 'Comp3', 'Comp1', 'Comp2', 'Comp3'],
                          'Description': ['comp desc', 'comp desc', 'comp desc', 'comp desc', 'comp desc', 'comp desc', 'comp desc', 'comp desc', 'comp desc'],
                          'Price': [60, 30, 180, 100, 150, 160, 170, 200, 80]})
```

Now here's code you need

```
# Read File
csv_input = pd.read_csv("d:\python programs\chairs.csv")

# Remove duplicates
csv_input = csv_input.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'])

# Remove records with price under 50
csv_input =  csv_input[csv_input['Price'] >= 50]

# Create Quality Column
csv_input["Quality"] = np.where(csv_input['Price']>125, 'High', 'Average')

# Save to CSV    
csv_input.to_csv("d:\python programs\output2.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I like using the numpy.where command to create the Quality column and set the value in one go. I was doing this with 2 lines before, and thought about using an if statement... I like this better... Also thank you for putting the comments, a lot of responses do not include them.

Comment: additional question, this is working, however when I looked at the file that I actually download in the script (using the requests library), I noted that the price has a leading $ and trailing.00 (price = $299.00), as expected this trhows an error (TypeError between str and int). So what is the most effcient way to wrap the price as an int(or should it be a float?)?

Comment: @PythonNewb  The best way would be to read it as a string. Then remove leading $, for example using next code  df['Price'] = df['Price'].str[1:]. Then convert to int using next code df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype('int64')